# Make Postfix reject To:mydestination from web but accept if locally sent, and still accept To:virtual_mailbox_domains from web

Tags: postfix

I almost have my perfect Postfix (v3.3.1) setup on CentOS8. My goals are to:

- Allow services to send emails to linux users. (crontab to root)
- Do not accept public email for linux users. (root@domain.com)
- Define which users to receive public email without making linux users for them.

I managed to accomplish the above but with one side effect i can't figure out how to prevent. Some of what i have done so far:

```
myhostname = server.foobar.com
mydomain = foobar.com
myorigin = $myhostname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail

virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = foobar.com
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/email/
```

This bit tells Postfix any mail sent by a service to a user gets $myhostname added (user@server.foobar.com) and it gets delivered to the standard system email in `/var/spool/mail`.

Any email sent to a linux user at the domain as user@foobar.com gets treated as a virtual domain, looks for a virtual user and if there isn't one rejects the email.

If i add a virtual user (like webmaster) any email sent to that user (webmaster@foobar.com) gets accepted and delivered to `/var/spool/email/...` keeping public email separate from system email.

---

**THE Problem...**

If anyone gets wise enough to send an email to the hostname (user@server.foobar.com) from the internet it gets accepted and delivered into `/var/spool/mail`. I can't figure out how to block this.

---

I have tried setting `default_transport = error:Domain doesn't accept email.` but that didn't change the behavior. The docs do not support this feature but i saw it mentioned in a forum so i tried it.

It is not important for me to keep linux users as user@$myhostname, this was just the only way i could figure out how to keep linux users separate from virtual users on the same domain name to prevent spammers from hitting root@foobar.com, postmaster@foobar.com, etc.

Other config settings if important:

```
html_directory = no
local_recipient_maps =
luser_relay = postmaster
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost
mydomain = foobar.com
myhostname = server.foobar.com
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $myhostname
relay_domains =
relayhost =
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/email/
virtual_mailbox_domains = foobar.com
virtual_transport = virtual
```

Any ideas or another way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution.**

Keeping the `myorigin = $myhostname` way of separating local users from virtual users on the same domain as stated in my question.

In the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` section of `main.cf`, after you `permit_mynetworks` add `check_recipient_access` pointing to a list. I used `hash:`, it looked something like:

```
# Don't include the "...", its just to show this is among other settings

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   ...
   permit_mynetworks
   check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/block_mydomain
   ...
```

Then create the list/hash file `/etc/postfix/block_mydomain`

```
hostname.domain.com     513 Invalid domain.
```

Save the file and run `postmap block_mydomain` to create the *.db version.

Then restart postfix `systemctl restart postfix` and that should do it.

I tested it and i can send mail using the sendmail command locally to any linux user. Crontab can send email to local linux users. But if you send an email from the internet to `user@hostname.domain.com` it gets bounced. And in case you're wondering the double-bounce@hostname.domain.com still gets accepted and discarded.